# Rhino ETL - cancel EtlProcess part way through

Tags: c#, rhino-etl

I have a Rhino ETL process that performs several sequential actions, the first of which is to go to a SQL Server database and retrieve some rows (i.e. the "extract" part of the overall process).

I want to make the `EtlProcess` bomb out if there were no rows returned at this stage. How would I go about this? I've taken a stab at overriding `OnFinishedProcessing()` but I can't see an obvious way to signal that the `EtlProcess` should bomb out.

What I have so far:

```
protected override void OnFinishedProcessing(IOperation op)
{
    var sqlExtractionOperation = op as SqlExtractionOperation;
    if (sqlExtractionOperation != null)
    {
        if (sqlExtractionOperation.Statistics.OutputtedRows == 0)
        {
            //TODO: figure out how to make it stop here
        }
    }

    base.OnFinishedProcessing(op);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for me was to tell the `EtlProcess` to execute in single-threaded mode.

By default, each Rhino ETL operation is executed on a separate worker thread, which means any exceptions raised by individual operations are swallowed by default. (The queued worker threads wait in series for each other's data to come through - at least, that is what I got from a quick bit of debugging of the source)

To make an `EtlProcess` execute in single-threaded mode, just add this to its constructor:

```
PipelineExecuter = new SingleThreadedPipelineExecuter();
```

Throwing an exception inside any of the process's operations will then cause the entire process to bomb out. You can record errors at the end of the process by overriding `PostProcessing()`:

```
protected override void PostProcessing()
{
    base.PostProcessing();

    if (!PipelineExecuter.HasErrors)
        Info("Process completed successfully");
    else
        Warn("Process failed");
}
```